# how to remove unwanted soap envelop attribute tag value using XSLT transform

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have soap envelop containing xml. I want to remove that tag value. I am using saxon9 parser. my input xml is:

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
             <soapenv:Envelope  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org  /soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
             <soapenv:Body><ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
                  <Document xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
              <Attributes><Attribute name="duration">0:00:13.629</Attribute><Attribute name="count">121</Attribute><Attribute name="entity">Requisition</Attribute>
             <Attribute name="mode">XML</Attribute>
            <Attribute name="version">http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01</Attribute>
            </Attributes><Content>
            <ExportXML xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
           <record>
    <field name="JobAction">2</field>
    <field name="JobType">false</field>
    <field name="JobPositionPostingID">000065</field>
    <field name="JobFunctionCode">ADMINISTRATION</field>
    </record>
      </ExportXML></Content></Document></ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse>   
      </soapenv:Body>    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

my xsl file is like this

```
               <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
           <xsl:output  indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
           <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

          <xsl:template match="*:field">
          <xsl:element name="{lower-case(@name)}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>     
          </xsl:element>
          </xsl:template>
          <xsl:template match="*:ExportXML">
           <JobPositionPostings>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
           </JobPositionPostings>
        </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="*:record">
     <JobPositionPosting>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*:field[starts-with(@name,'JobAction')]"/>
       <HiringOrg>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*:field[starts-with(@name,'JobType')]"/>
     <Industry>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*:field[starts-with(@name,'JobPositionPostingID')]"/>
        </Industry>
       </HiringOrg>
       </JobPositionPosting>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*:field[starts-with(@name,'JobFeedResponseEmail')]"/>
      </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="*:field[@name='TypeName']"/>
      <xsl:template match="*:field[@name='TypeName']" mode="title">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>  
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting output like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>**0:00:13.629121RequisitionXMLhttp://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01**<JobPositionPostings xmlns:soap="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
    <JobPositionPosting>
  <jobaction>2</jobaction>
  <jobtype>false</jobtype>
  <jobpositionpostingid>000065</jobpositionpostingid>
  <HiringOrg>
```

after xml tag it is picking all attribute tag value which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a empty template like this one

```
 <xsl:template match="*:Attributes"/>
```

(Notice the slash at end)

All Attributes elements will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to care about anything outside the `<Content>` you could add an extra template to jump straight to that and ignore the rest:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*:Content[1]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanku very much. i got output properly.i was seaching this from so much times .really thanks